# How to update options on an existing reference in Rails migration

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

How can I write a migration file to add an option to an existing model relationship? The existing table data must be preserved.

For example, I have existing:

```
class Chapter < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :org
end
```

Which I want to update to:

```
class Chapter < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :org, touch: true
end
```

How do I write the migration file for this? (Or for any other reference options changes?)

Would add_reference update the existing column? or add a new one?

```
class AddChapterToOrg < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :org, :chapter, touch: true
  end
end
```

Comment: touch true doesn't need any database changes. No migration. Is there some other option you have in mind? Like uniqueness validation (though should have a unique index in db) or optional/required (which should have null checks in db)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`touch: true` is an option to the `belongs_to` method and tells Rails to update the associated object's timestamp when the current object's timestamp is updated. This touch is handled by Rails and not by the database engine.

That said, when you add `touch: true` to a `belongs_to` association then there is no need to run a database migration because the database schema doesn't need to change to support this.